# Java-script create columns and rows based on user input

Tags: javascript, loops, user-input

This is a JavaScript homework question that has taken me far too long to search the web to figure out.  Based on learning loops, while, do while, and for loops.  I am to:

> Prompt the user for a number of rows
> and a number of columns. Using the * output the *
> character in the row and column pattern requested
> by the user. If the user requests 2 rows and 2
> columns you should output:

**

**>

Code thus far:

\\  var row = prompt("How many rows?")
var column = prompt("How many columns?") \\

I would appreciate the guidance that could lead me to the answer.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: \\\ var tr = document.createElement(tr);
        var td = document.createElement(td);
        
        var tr1 = parseInt(row);
        var td1 = parseInt(column);
        
        var a = tr * tr1;
        var b = td * td1;
        document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = tr + td;     \\\  I have watched every video before this exercise to see if I missed something, though there is nothing about taking user input and creating something from it such as rows and columns.  I do know how to take user input and multiply it, though not sure on creating a design from it

Comment: Hi, please edit your post and put your code to the post. It is very hard to read codes through comments. Remember to format your code to make it more readable. You can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) Stack Overflow editing help to guide you on how do you format your codes. Goodluck :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have mentioned the output is in the form of a table, we use two loops here. The first one is to append every row and the nested loop is to append every column. `colData.innerHTML = "*"` gives the value/pattern that's supposed to be included in each column. 
In the html file, this entire table is appended into the element that has `pattern` as its ID attribute.

```
let table = document.createElement('table');
let tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

table.appendChild(tbody);
document.getElementById('pattern').appendChild(table);

var row = prompt("How many rows?");
var column = prompt("How many columns?");

for(let i = 0 ; i< row; i++){
    let rowVal = document.createElement('tr');
    for(let j = 0; j< column; j++){
        let colData = document.createElement('td');
        colData.innerHTML = "*";
        rowVal.appendChild(colData);
    }
    
    tbody.appendChild(rowVal);
}
```

Comment: This is so much help!  As I am learning Java-script as a complete beginner through an online course, I was not taught about create element and appendChild.  To this point I have learned about Conditionals, variables, operators, loops (while, do while, and for).  Thanks for answering the question, but more importantly for breaking it down for me!  If you have a specific resource to help, let me know!  I am currently running through w3schools resource to get a better understanding.

Comment: Glad to know it helped! W3schools is a pretty good starting point. The other methods you've mentioned comes under HTML DOM. You can read more about it here - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp